# How to call a parent directive link function from a child directive's link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two directives, `directiveA` and `directiveB` both with `link` functions. How can I call a function belonging to `directiveA` from `directiveB`?

The way I have my code set up so far is:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('directiveA', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'directiveA.html',
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.directiveAAlert = function () {
                alert('This is A');
            }
        }
    }
});

angular.module('myApp').directive('directiveB', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            onButtonClicked: '='
        }
        templateUrl: 'directiveB.html',
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.showAlert = function () {
                scope.onButtonClicked();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

In `directiveA.html`:

```
<directive-b onButtonClicked='directiveAAlert'></directive-b>
```

In `directiveB.html`:

```
<button ng-click='showAlert()'></button>
```

But when I click the button, I get an error saying `TypeError: scope.onLogInButtonClicked is not a function at Scope.link.scope.showAlert`.

How do I simply define and call this same function from the child directive?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `require` option of directive where you can mention the other directive would be on same element or it may be my parent using `^` inside `require` property in directive API. When you used `require: ^parentDirective` that will give you access of the `parentDirective` controller in the link function `childDirective` who requires it.

Additionally you need to correct you template html which should have attributes as `-` separated by replacing its cammelcase case.

**directiveA.html:**

```
<directive-b on-button-clicked='directiveAAlert()'></directive-b>
```

**directiveB.html**

```
<button ng-click='showAlert()'></button>
```

**Code**

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('directiveA', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'directiveA.html',
        link: function (scope) {
            //code here
        },
        controller: function($scope){
           scope.directiveAAlert = function () {
                alert('This is A');
            }
        }
    }
});

angular.module('myApp').directive('directiveB', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            onButtonClicked: '='
        },
        require: '^directiveA',
        templateUrl: 'directiveB.html',
        link: function (scope,element,attrs, ctrl) {
            scope.showAlert = function () {
                ctrl.onButtonClicked(); //ctrl has access to the directive a controller.
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Why migrate `directiveAAlert` to a controller? I simply changed the attribute from camel case to `on-button-clicked` and it solved my problem. (I didn't need to create a controller and require it in the child for it to work)

Comment: @roscioli oh..thats worked because you did passed that method in isolated scope..If you don't pass that in isolated scope then you could directly call the parent directive method without passing it in isolated scope..